# Is it possible to switch to previously opened tab instead of opening a new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

In the website I am building I have a link to another webpage set with a target of _blank to open in a new tab.

If I click the link and then switch back to the 1st page and click the link again it opens a 3rd tab.

Is there any way to get the browser to just switch back to the already open tab for the 2nd webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use target="secondPage", this create a named window/tab and every links that a user click that has this target will be opened in this page.

Other than this, I don't think it's possible nor a good thing. You should not tell the user how to manage his tabs/windows.

Comment: Kristian is right, if you're going to open a new window/tab, it should indeed be a *new* window/tab. If you use the same window/tab, via naming it, there's often no indication to the user when something has happened, because that window/tab will just silently reload in the background. This will often lead users to furiously click the link multiple times, confused as to why nothing is happening from their perspective.

Comment: Personally I would not want to do this but the Customer asked us if it was possible so I thought I would double check. If the named tab doesn't switch to it when you click a second time, that would probably be worse than opening a new one. Thanks though.

Comment: Read this: http://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/, it tells you when to use target=_blank and when not to.